# Splitting the plane to fit convexes

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm trying to show the following :

Let $K,L$ two closed convexes of $\mathbb{R}^2,O=(0,0)$

- If $O\notin K$ then there exists a straight line $D$ going through $O$ such that $K$ is in one of the half of plane defined by $D$
- If $K$ is bounded and does not intersect with $L$ then there exists a straight line $D$ such that $K$,$L$ are in two distinct halves of plan defined by $D$

---

Those two properties are really easy to understand intuitively or with a graph, but I haven't been able to find a proper mathematical proof.

Comment: Are the sets assumed open or closed? If not, you have to be careful: Consider the example where $K$ consists of points with $x^2+y^2<1$ and either $y>0$ or $y=0$ and $x>0$. Then let $L=-K$ (i.e., the reflection of $K$ through the origin).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen They're closed, thanks, I forgot to add that.

Comment: By the way, it seems that this is a general situation not only for the plane, but for a locally convex space $X$, satisfying the Hahn-Banach Theorem. Since $K$ is closed, by [Hahn-Banach separation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem) there exist a real number $\varepsilon>0$ and a linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(O)=0$ and $f|K>\varepsilon$. Geometrically it should mean that there is a hyperplane strictly separating the point $O$ from the set $K$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Absolutely. However, the Hahn–Banach separation theorem is *much* easier in Hilbert spaces! The proof outlined by me and elaborated by Mike Miller works equally well in that more general setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to the first problem. (For these sorts of problems I suggest drawing pictures - it's amazing how helpful blobs on a page can be.) Harald's gives you the second.

Because $K$ is closed, there's a point in $K$ of minimal distance to the origin; call it $v=(x,y)$. Then consider the normal line $D = \text{span}(-y,x)$. It suffices to show that $K \cap D = \varnothing$. Suppose not; say $(-ty,tx) \in K$. Because $v$ had minimal distance to the origin, $t \geq 1$. By convexity, every point of the form $s(-ty,tx) + (1-s)(x,y) \in K$ for $0 \leq s \leq 1$. Let's take the norm of this point. After some algebra, we obtain $$\sqrt{(1-s)^2+s^2t^2}\|v\|.$$
But for $s$ sufficiently small (pick $0 < s < \frac{2}{1+t}$), the first term is less than 1; this contradicts that $v$ was the point of $K$ of least norm. So $K \cap D = \varnothing$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

**Two hints for the price of one:** For the first one, consider the point $P\in K$ closest to the origin, and take $D$ to be normal to the line from $O$ to $P$.

For the second one, apply the first one to the set $K-L=\{u-v\colon u\in K, v\in L\}$.